# How to show datetime on x-axis?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh to update some real-time data with datetime. I tried some ways but I am still failing to do it successfully.

This is my code.

```
from bokeh.driving import linear 
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from random import randint
import datetime
import random 

p = figure(title='Test Data',x_axis_type='datetime')
p = figure(plot_width=1300, plot_height=500)
r1 = p.line([], [], color="firebrick", line_width=2)
ds1 = r1.data_source 

@linear()
def update(step):
    global dsl
    ds1.data['x'].append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
    ds1.data['y'].append(random.randint(0,100)) 
    ds1.trigger('data', ds1.data, ds1.data) 

curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 2000)
```

If I modified

```
ds1.data['x'].append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

to

```
ds1.data['x'].append(step)
```

the code can run.

Can someone please give me a hint to make x_axis show the datetime?

Comment: Thanks Gino to edit my article as organized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates should not be strings. They should be:

- real datetime types e.g. any of the Python, NumPy, or Pandas datetime types will work
- a numeric timestamp, specifically, *milliseconds since epoch*